# PHP - Email Personalisation string replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm putting together an email personalisation library, so as with email mailers like Mailchimp and Campaign Monitor, you can have a certain personalisation say [FNAME] and it'll replace the string with the customers firstname.

If I've got text such as the following:

```
$source = 'Hello [FNAME-fallback="there"]';
```

What I want to do is replace FNAME with `$customer->fname` if it exists, otherwise replace it with the fallback.

The difficulty is, that users can also enter in `[FNAME]` and then it should just attempt a replace without any fallback and obviously remove [FNAME] even if there's no firstname set.

I've got as far as this:

```
$personalisations = array(
    'FNAME',
    'LNAME',
    'CNAME'
);

$match  = '/\[(?:' . implode('|', $personalisations) . ')(?:\-[\s]*fallback=\")*(.{0,})\"\]/i';
$replace    = '$1';
$source     = 'Hello [FNAME-fallback="there"]';

$text   = preg_replace($match, $replace, $source);
```

That part works fine in replacing the FNAME with 'there', but I need to factor in that there might not be a `'-fallback="there"'` given, and also I need to replace it with `$customer->fname` if it's not empty.. So presumably, I need to find which of the personalisations it matched as $1, and then set:

```
$replace = !empty($customer->fname) ? $customer->fname : '$1'
```

Also needs to factor in that it might be fname, lname or cname etc.

I'm not sure if I'm confusing matters by trying to perform the whole lot in one function, but effectively I need the most efficient method as the function's going to be run over and over again for each customer. Can any regex hero point me in the right direction with this one? I think I'm going the right way but I just cant fathom out the last part...

Thanks,

Christian

Comment: Instead of writing your own templating engine, you might consider using one of the more established ones, such as [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

Comment: Sounds a bit overkill for the above needs.. I'm sure there must be an expression not far off what I've got above to match my needs.. Or at least I hope so!

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with regex - what are you going to do when someone provides multiple replacement parameters on a single line, e.g. if the source was something like `'Hello [FNAME-fallback="first"] [LNAME-fallback="last"]'`? I realize templating might seem like overkill, but they're mature, developed solutions, that can handle most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you instead provide the default values in a separate field, outside the template, you could do something like this:

```
$personalisations = array(
    'FNAME',
    'LNAME',
    'CNAME'
);

$defaults = array(
    'FNAME' => 'first',
    'LNAME' => 'last',
    'CNAME' => 'class',
);

$match = array();
$replace = array();

for ($personalinations as $key) {
    $match[] = "/[$key]/";
    if (isset($customer->$key)) {
        $replace[] = $customer->$key;   
    } else { 
        $replace[] = $defaults[$key];
    }
}

$source     = 'Hello [FNAME-fallback="there"]';

$text = preg_replace($match, $replace, $source);
```

This should handle multiple replacements in a single `$source`.  I still think a templating engine would be much more robust, and if you need to make changes down the line, much easier to maintain.